# how to install socket.io client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is it possible to reference socket.io client library with a relative path like:

```
src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

instead of

```
src="https://miweb:6969/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

Also to connect the library we do:

```
var websocket = io.connect ("https://miweb.com:6969");
```

I have seen some do:

```
var websocket = io.connect ("/");
```

As if socket.io were running on the same port and were running on the same project.

What should I do to our server to work this way?

Comment: you can replace the hard-coded path with properties of window.location

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your webpage is served from the same location than Socket.io, you can do this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('/');
  socket...
</script>
```

But if the page is in another domain you should use an absolute url.

Comment: To whom it may interezar and need to connect to the same port to your server either node.js or attend solucitudes http "hybrid application" 


use the same port is an advantage to allow communication via sockets.io is on port 443 because it is the only port that allows communication with websockets for clients who are in networks with proxy, in addition to meeting the normal web server applications 

the option to do is to create an abstraction of websockets: http://www.securityartwork.es/2013/06/13/abstrayendo-websockets-ssl/ 

regards